# Access HTML multiple button tag value having same class Value created in PHP and getting in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hi I can access the values of these buttons

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
$newArray[] = "<input type='button' name='$i' value='($i)' class='najam' id='$i' onclick='myFunction();' />";
}
```

**myFunction**

```
 function myFunction(){
// here to get the values of the buttons
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the PHP to pass the element:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
$newArray[] = "<input type='button' name='$i' value='($i)' class='najam' id='$i' onclick='myFunction(this);' />";
}
```

and do

```
function myFunction(elem){
    alert(elem.value);
}
```

or just use a proper event handler

```
$('.najam').on('click', function() {
    alert(this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

on the button, set the onClick or even to `myFunction({$i})`

in in your javascript:

```
function myfunction(id){
    //use id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [Jquery](http://jquery.com/).

```
$(".najam") // this is the selector for all items with the class "najam"
```

And then you can use it with methods like `.click()`, `.each()`, etc.

Comment: Other than linking the jQuery home page, it may be worth to show how to use it to solve the OP problem.